# Perl LibXML print extra "text" tag

Tags: xml, linux, perl, svn, libxml2

I am trying to read tags from XML using LibXML. I can print all the tags; however, for some reason it also prints "text" tag which is not part of my XML. Anyone can explain to me what causes this behavior? Any work around? If next time I have an XML tag with a "text" tag, then how can I distinguish that "text" tag from the extra "text" tag that is generated by LibXML?

Here's my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<log>
<logentry
   revision="935">
<author>darwin</author>
<date>2011-06-28T01:00:18.997106Z</date>
<msg>reintegrate branch</msg>
</logentry>
<logentry
   revision="931">
<author>darwin</author>
<date>2011-06-21T22:15:01.881607Z</date>
<msg>reintegrate branch</msg>
</logentry>
</log>
```

I read the XML using the following code:

```
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->parse_string($svnInfo);
my $root = $doc->getDocumentElement();
my @nodes=$root->childNodes();

foreach my $child(@nodes) {
        my $name = $child -> nodeName();
        my @atts = $child -> getAttributes();
        print "\n${name} (";

        print ")\n";
}
```

This is my output:

```
text ()

logentry ()

text ()

logentry ()

text ()
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `$parser->keep_blanks(0)` before `my $doc = $parser->parse_string($svnInfo);`

**EDIT** changed no_blanks to keep_blanks

Comment: Gives me an error: "Can't locate auto/XML/LibXML/no_blanks.al".
I'm using perl 5.8.8, maybe that function does not included in the library.

Comment: Stupid me, that was old.  Try the inverse (and see Edit), `$parser->keep_blanks(0);`

Comment: I recommend you also check out Jim G's answer -- it is important to note *why* `text()` was being printed by your script.

Answer (score 7):

Because there's a whitespace-only text node (containing a newline) between the last `</logentry>` and the `</log>`.  Notice also the first `text()`, which corresponds to the newline text node between `<log>` and the first `<logentry>`.

Comment: What? is that what causes it? This is weird, because what I have is just a regular XML. Isn't XML reader is supposedly ignoring all the white spaces (not part of a tag)? Also, Why does it assign the white space as "text" tag? What if I have a "text" tag? how do I know which one is which (assume I have /n as well on my "text" tag)? 

Btw, thanks for pointing that out. Do you know any workaround to fix this?

Comment: Your particular implementation of the XML reader may provide an option to ignore whitespace-only nodes, but in general the parser has no way to know if they're significant to _you_, so it returns them.  You're free to ignore them if you want.